# Use of Shrink after rebuilding Indexes in sql server 2005

Tags: index, maintenance, shrink

I need to create a weekly database plan for my company's databases (5.8Gb), now I want to rebuild the Indexes, and then want to trigger a Shrink operation. Now I know Shrink creates  Index defragmentation, so can anyone guide me how to create this maintenance plan... Your suggestion will be very much valuable to me...Please

Comment: But the data shrink is going to ruin all your indexes that you've just rebuilt - don't do this! Actually, I'd recommend an `Index Rebuild` after each data shrink operation!

Answer (score 3):

Paul Randal answers your question [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx):

> Data file shrink should never be  part of regular maintenance, and you
>   should NEVER, NEVER have auto-shrink enabled. I tried to have it
>   removed from the product for SQL 2005 and SQL 2008 when I was in a
>   position to do so - the only reason it's still there is for backwards
>   compatibility. **Don't fall into the trap of having a maintenance plan
>   that rebuilds all indexes and then tries to reclaim the space required
>   to rebuild the indexes by running a shrink - that's a zero-sum game
>   where all you do is generate a log of transaction log for no actual
>   gain in performance.**
>
> So what if you *do* need to run a shrink? For instance, if you've
>   deleted a large proportion of a very large database and the database
>   isn't likely to grow, or you need to empty a file before removing it?
>
> The method I like to recommend is as follows:
>
> - Create a new filegroup
> - Move all affected tables and indexes into the new filegroup using the CREATE INDEX ... WITH (DROP_EXISTING) ON  syntax, to move the tables and remove fragmentation from
>     them at the same time
> - Drop the old filegroup that you were going to shrink anyway (or shrink it way down if its the primary filegroup)